# React Native: crash when running "fetch"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crash, fetch

I am facing problem with Ract Native when use this command

`npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

the app crash when it run into the line with fetch function

```
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                serverurl,
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                }
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(error)
        }
```

I also check the

`adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V AndroidRuntime:V`

but could not find the reason

hope some one can help me

thank you

```
12-06 21:50:37.933  3441 15277 I ReactNativeJS: Running "Dblexplx" with {"rootTag":1}
12-06 21:50:38.278  3441 15277 I ReactNativeJS: null
12-06 21:50:38.287  3441  3441 I ReactNative: [GESTURE HANDLER] Initialize gesture handler for root view com.facebook.react.ReactRootView{c4ccf06 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1467 #1}
12-06 21:50:38.396  3441 15277 I ReactNativeJS: [BleError: Device is not authorized to use BluetoothLE]
12-06 21:52:26.242  3441 15277 I ReactNativeJS: Error
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.dblexplx, PID: 3441
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.bridge.UnexpectedNativeTypeException: Value for message cannot be cast from Boolean to String
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.checkInstance(ReadableNativeMap.java:140)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getNullableValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:128)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getString(ReadableNativeMap.java:162)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule.showAlert(DialogModule.java:195)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
12-06 21:52:26.283  3441 15278 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: I think it might be choking on console.error. Can you remove it and see what happens?

Comment: you are defining `err` in the `catch (err)`  block and then printing `error` in `console.error(error)`

Comment: @windowsill  and Athavan T:  thank you for your message, I tried remove console.error  line and the app donnot crash,. but the the fetch don't work even the authentication server is online (work in debug mode only). If I remove try and catch, the app will crash when it run the fetch line.

Comment: That's an entirely different problem. Try console.log(err) in your catch and look at what error is returned.